# node-mysql2 and prepared statements

Tags: mysql, node.js, pdo

I'd like to know what could I use as alternative for PHP PDO in Node.js

I've found [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2), they talk about **`prepared statements`** but I can't find a way to cache the statement to reuse it.

With PHP I do:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare('SELECT 1+? AS test1');
$sth->execute( Array(10) );
$sth->execute( Array(20) );
```

And with this I don't prepare the query each time, I juse use the prepared one changing the variable value.

With node-mysql2 instead I do:

```
connection.execute('SELECT 1+? AS test1', [10], function(err, rows) {
  //
});
```

But I can't find a way to take advantages by the prepared statement feature.

Answer (score 4):

Referencing [this thread](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/274) near the end you can see this answer to your question:

> Sorry, I was completely wrong about node-mysql2. It does indeed
>   prepare once. The API led me to believe that it didn't have a separate
>   prepare and execute, but I looked at the code and found that it does
>   have a cache that reuses the prepared statement if you use the same
>   query text.
>
> I was a bit nasty when I posted that comment. I was frustrated. Sorry
>   about that.